# enable inflections on Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to add inflection rules for Italian on a Rails5 app.

So I updated `initializers/inflections.rb` as follows.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:it) do |inflect|
   inflect.plural /^([\w]*)o/i, '\1i'
   inflect.plural /^([\w]*)a/i, '\1e'
   inflect.uncountable %w( attività )
 end
```

But after restarting the server, English rules are still used.

The locale is correctly set to `:it` (the UI is correctly localized) but words are pluralized using english rules.

Do I have somehow to enable the rules I have defined?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Rails docs for pluralize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-pluralize) seem to indicate that the locale has to be passed into the pluralize method as an argument, rather than automatically being deduced from your app's locale. So something like:

```
pluralize("cane", :it)
# or directly on string
"cane".pluralize(2, :it)
```

...should work.

If you have a multi-locale app you can replace `:it` with `I18n.locale` to have the inflection locale change depending on your user's locale.

### Edit

You might want to look at your rules again though! As currently

```
"cane".pluralize(:it) #=> "cene"
```

which even I (who don't speak italian at all) can see is wrong. It's happening because the end of string anchor is missing from your regex, so the first instance of a is being picked up. Simply add `\z` at the end of your regex to ensure that only the final character is recognized – I would recommend using `\A` instead of `^` as well:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:it) do |inflect|
  inflect.plural /\A([\w]*)o\z/i, '\1i'
  inflect.plural /\A([\w]*)a\z/i, '\1e'
  inflect.uncountable %w( attività )
end
```

Comment: [reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#regular-expressions) for `\A` and `\z` over `^` and `$`.  TLDR: security.

Comment: Thanks for your help. By the way, the regex as I tried to define don't work. After looking at the default English inflection  rules, I was able to correctly inflect Italian words as follows ```inflect.plural(/(o|e)$/, 'i')
   inflect.plural(/a$/, 'e')```.